# Need help getting listbox item text from secondary form to main form

Tags: c#

I have been looking all over the Internet for this and have found similar, but none of it will work for me. Everything I have found assumes the listbox is on the main form and not the secondary form, or the code is for an older version of C# or Visual Studio (I am using VS2008).

I am creating a web browser that has a button on the main form (called frmMyBrowser) to open a dialog (frmBookmarks) with a listbox (lstBookmark) with bookmarked URLs. I need to be able to double click on an item (the bookmarked URL) and have the text pasted into the address bar (cmbAddress) of the main form.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: please post the code you have so far that would help others to understand the errors and to help you get you the answers.

Comment: You either need some clientside programming to retrieve the value from the frmBookmarks, and copy it to the cmbAddress.
Or you can do it serverside and use an updatepanel on the mainform to set the new value.

Comment: Maybe you could store the result of the dialog in a string that you can access from the main form? And a note, it's against common C# naming convention to use Hungarian notation. For example your `lstBookmark` should be called `Bookmark(List)Box`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I create the window at runtime, I can get it to work. In case anyone is interested, the code I used is below.

public void frmMyBrowser_ShowFavorites(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

        frmFavorites.ShowIcon = false;
        frmFavorites.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        frmFavorites.MinimizeBox = false;
        frmFavorites.MaximizeBox = false;
        frmFavorites.ControlBox = false;
        frmFavorites.Text = "Bookmarks";
        frmFavorites.Width = 500;
        frmFavorites.Height = 350;
        frmFavorites.Controls.Add(lstFavorites);
        frmFavorites.Controls.Add(btnRemoveFavorite);
        frmFavorites.Controls.Add(btnAddFavorite);
        frmFavorites.Controls.Add(btnCloseFavorites);
        frmFavorites.Controls.Add(txtCurrentUrl);
        lstFavorites.Width = 484;
        lstFavorites.Height = 245;
        btnRemoveFavorite.Location = new Point(8, 280);
        btnAddFavorite.Location = new Point(8, 255);
        btnCloseFavorites.Location = new Point(400, 255);
        txtCurrentUrl.Location = new Point(110, 255);
        txtCurrentUrl.Size = new Size(255, 20);
        btnAddFavorite.Text = "Add";
        btnRemoveFavorite.Text = "Remove";
        btnCloseFavorites.Text = "Close";
        txtCurrentUrl.Text = wbBrowser.Url.ToString();
        btnAddFavorite.Click += new EventHandler(btnAddFavorite_Click);
        btnRemoveFavorite.Click += new EventHandler(btnRemoveFavorite_Click);
        frmFavorites.Load += new EventHandler(frmFavorites_Load);
        btnCloseFavorites.Click += new EventHandler(btnCloseFavorites_Click);
        lstFavorites.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(lstFavorites_MouseDoubleClick);
        frmFavorites.Show();
}

public void btnCloseFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (lstFavorites.Items.Count > 0)
{
using (StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@Application.StartupPath + "\\favorites.txt"))
{
for (int i = 0; i < lstFavorites.Items.Count; i++)

{

writer.WriteLine(lstFavorites.Items[i].ToString());

}

writer.Close();
}

}
    frmFavorites.Hide();
}

public void btnAddFavorite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string strFavoriteAddress = wbBrowser.Url.ToString();
        if (!lstFavorites.Items.Contains(strFavoriteAddress))
        {
            lstFavorites.Items.Add(strFavoriteAddress);
            MessageBox.Show("Favorite Added", "Message");

        }
        else if (lstFavorites.Items.Contains(strFavoriteAddress))
        {   
            MessageBox.Show("This site already exists in your Favorites list!", "Error");

        }
        else 
        {

        }


    }
    public void btnRemoveFavorite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lstFavorites.Items.RemoveAt(lstFavorites.SelectedIndices[0]);

        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to select an item", "Error");

        }

    }
    public void frmFavorites_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@Application.StartupPath + "\\favorites.txt"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        string strListItem = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strListItem))
                        {
                            lstFavorites.Items.Add(strListItem);
                        }
                    }

                }
                reader.Close();
            }



        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occured", "Error");
        }

    }
    private void lstFavorites_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string strSelectedAddress = lstFavorites.Text.ToString();
        cmbAddress.Text = strSelectedAddress;
        wbBrowser.Navigate(strSelectedAddress);
        frmFavorites.Hide();
    }
```